# SpringBoot Maven project

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, dependencies, parent

when trying to run the spring boot maven project on eclipse getting that error .
"Launch configuration Attacher references non-existing project demo2."
Anyone please help to fix that error.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make sure your project is a Java Project, and not a Simple project. 
You can check that the navigator shows a little blue 'J' associated with the folder.If it does not shows,it means it is a Simple project.
You can create a Java project File>New>Project>Java Project --projectName and Finish.

Or it can be possible that your java project was referencing to one of your previous project.
You can resolve this problem by changing some project setting-->
Project->properties->"Run/Debug Settings"->configure->edit-->Main tab(select current project).
Then select "Main class" by clicking on search button(it will be your class name)-->Ok.

Hope it will resolve your problem.